# Ensuring a div is 100% width, without ruining menu

Tags: html, css

Firstly, I'm new-ish to this, so please bear with me.

I've implemented a pretty cool 'fade on scroll script' to [my site.](http://cargocollective.com/btatest)

However, what I'm looking to do is have the image at the top span 100% width like [fastcocreate's](http://www.fastcocreate.com/) site.

This is the div I'm working with:

```
<div class="home" style="background-image: url(http://payload51.cargocollective.com/1/7/237315/3336908/HomeImage_o.jpg); background-attachment: fixed; height: 560px; width: 100%; opacity: 1; background-position-y: 0px; background-position-x: center; background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat; background-size: 100% 560px;"> 
</div>
```

Now I've tried adding a 'background-size: 100% auto;' to the div, which does the trick, except this does weird things to my text. For example, if I make the browser slimmer the text doesn't move with it – so I scrapped that idea.

Next I changed it to 'background-size: 100% 560px;' which solved this issue. But created another one is that the image squashes when you make the browser smaller, or stretches it when I make it wider.

I feel I'm closer with the one above, but I'm looking for a solution to the stretching image issue. Do I need to upload an image that's bigger than the current dimensions?

As I've said earlier [these guys](http://www.fastcocreate.com/) do a good job.

Answer (score 0):

it would appear that fastocreate has a min-width set to their image, have you tried a

```
min-width: 100%;
height: auto;
```

?

Im pretty sure thats what fastocreate does

best,
-b

*Also, try enabling the "inspect element" on your browser. Its super helpful when trying to mirror someone's style.

Edit:

in response to your comment, you could try making a jQuery function that would resize it.

for example

```
function resize(){
  var height = $('img').width / 2; //sets variable height to the width divided by 2
  $('img').height(height); // sets the value of the height to the variable height
};
```

or something like that.

Comment: when I add that to the div, the image disappears.